# How do assign a role to user after add to cart in ubercart in drupal 7?

Tags: ubercart

I am using ubercart for my site.. I need to assign a role to user after shopping with price base.. If user does $300 shopping then role 10%-role . if user does $400 shopping then 20%-role etc.. And remember these role next shopping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

1. Add a new rule on event **complete checkout**.
2. Give your required conditions.
3. Add **Assign role to user** as action.

For your scenario you can do it using multiple rules.

Hope this will help you.